# has_many :through using "master" table twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a has_many :through relationship using the "master" table twice:

[image: "Diagram of the relation"]

How I can do it?

Comment: What is the direction you want? Who has many what?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jeremie users have many friendships. a friendship has many users

Comment: @ArslanAli what I want is to create a relationship between the User model and the Friendship model where an User have many friendships and a friendship has many Users

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like:

```
Table: friendships
  id           : integer          
  friend_id    : integer
  friend_of_id : integer

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :friend,    class: :user, inverse_of: 
  belongs_to :friend_of, class: :user, inverse_of:
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships,    class: :friendship, foreign_key: :friend_of, inverse_of: friend_of
  has_many :friends,        through: :friendships
  has_many :friendships_of, class: :friendship, foreign_key: :friend, inverse_of: :friend
  has_many :friends_of,     through: :friendships
end
```

I hope I got all that right, the lack of good terminology makes it confusing and if you can come up with something better then it will make it much easier.

Given this code you can add:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def add_friend(friend)
   # left out checking if they are already a friend
   friendships.create!( friend: friend)
   friendships_of.create!( friend_of: friend)
 end
end
```